# I'm having a problem creating a sleeping potion

Tags: dresden-files

I have a character who is an alchemist.  His magical ability is nil other than related to the creation of potions.  So far, so good.

On `YS280`, the rules state:

> At the beginning of each session, you may declare what potions you
> have on hand to fill those slots, or otherwise leave them open. If you
> have an open slot and a successful Lore roll or a fate point to spend,
> you may later declare that you coincidentally have an appropriate
> potion. A given potion can only be used once, period, but it doesn’t
> face a surcharge for being usable by someone else.
>
> The effect strength
> of a potion, like enchanted items, is equal to the wizard’s Lore.

So, he normally keeps slots open for potions that he might need- especially to pull out during combat.  The question that has come up is, **what is "a successful Lore roll"**?

Since the potion is at a strength equal to his Lore, by the last sentence quoted above, I just went with he needs to roll above his Lore, i.e. a positive or even roll.  But I was wondering what was really meant...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means that *if* you want to leave the slots open, you can declare them later (which is a more convenient time) if you either:

- Pay a fate point to make it true
- Make a successful Lore test

Remember that unopposed rolls in Fate are always against a target number of 0 unless otherwise stated. Opting for the roll means risking failure, and on a success, the GM has the usual opportunity to alter the exact outcome by the degree of success relative to the ladder. For example, making a Mediocre roll to suddenly have a sleep potion on-hand (using an empty slot) might mean that it was made in a hurry and has interesting side effects, while a roll of Legendary might mean not only do you have the potion, but it's *already in your hand* as soon as you succeed.

Note that you neither have to roll nor pay a fate point for potions that are declared at the beginning of the session. It's only slots left empty for later that require a point or roll.

Comment: " Difficulty is set by the GM. Likely defaults to zero unless there's a good reason to set it harder. " -- Answer from Fred Hicks. and +1